# PreviewProvider and ObservedObject properties

Tags: swift, swiftui

how can I set a property to my CoreData Object which has the type `CDObject`, it has a property called `name: String`

My issue is now that I do not know how to set the name property in the `PreviewProvider`

Here is the code:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var obj: CDObject
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView(obj: CDObject())
    }
}
```

I would like to do something like, before passing it to the View:

```
let itm = CDObject()
itm.name = "Hello"
```

Comment: I have a convenience addSample method that returns an object in my manager and my CoreData service checks if Xcode is running in preview so it uses the standard preview container vs the shared container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the standard `PersistenceController` that comes with Xcode when you start a new project with CoreData just add the below method so Xcode returns the `.preview` `container` when you are running in preview.

```
    public static func previewAware() -> PersistenceController{
        //Identifies if XCode is running for previews
        if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1"{
            return PersistenceController.preview
        }else{
            return PersistenceController.shared
        }
    }
```

As for the rest you can use something like this.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct SamplePreviewView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.timestamp?.description ?? "nil")
    }
}
struct SamplePreviewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let svc = CoreDataPersistenceService()
    static var previews: some View {
        SamplePreviewView(item: svc.addSample())
    }
}

class CoreDataPersistenceService: NSObject {

    var persistenceController: PersistenceController

    init(isTest: Bool = false) {
        if isTest{
            self.persistenceController = PersistenceController.preview
        }else{
            self.persistenceController = PersistenceController.previewAware()
        }
        super.init()
    }
    func addSample() -> Item {
        let object = createObject()
        object.timestamp = Date()
        return object
    }
    //MARK: CRUD methods
    func createObject() -> Item {
        let result = Item.init(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the `previewAware()` function? In the app? In the view file?  in it's own file? How is it called? Does just adding it somewhere end up "registering" it somehow?

Comment: @raddevus anywhere in the PersistenceController. That object comes in any standard Xcode project with CoreData

Comment: Ok, I got it now. That was my missing piece.  Thanks for lending a hand.