# SwiftUI Preview with Core Data: invalid NSEntityDescription

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I'm trying to have my SwiftUI Previews work with an in memory Core Data Stack (from Xcode Template). As soon as I call Entity.entity(), I get the following error message:

```
let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
let newBoatMO = Entity(entity: Entity.entity(), insertInto: context)
```

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'Entity' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'`

I checked in that the name in `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name:` is correct, I also checked in my `.xcdatamodeld`, the Entity name is correct, the module is empty (ie Global Namespace), and I have this `@objc(Entity)` at the top of my NSManagedObject subclass.

If I use the non-memory Stack, the Preview works. It's as if the Model was not loaded if I use the in-memory Stack.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties/67408828#67408828

Comment: Did you find any solution for this by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

For me this was fixed by using `public convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext)` rather then the designated `public init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?)`.

So:

```
Entity(context: context)
```

instead of

```
Entity(entity: Entity.entity(), insertInto: context)
```

---

Some background:

I had this error when I had 'overridden' the default `convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext)`. So I solved it by switching (back) to the built-in version.

Before my `Location+CoreDataClass` looked like this:

```
@objc(Location)
public class Location: NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init(entity: Location.entity(), insertInto: moc) // <- Error
        timestamp = Date()
    }
}
```

and afterwards like this:

```
@objc(Location)
public class Location: NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(into c: NSManagedObjectContext, timestamp: Date = Date()) {
        self.init(context: c) // <- No error
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what causes the error, but maybe this helps someone into the right direction. Make sure the `self.init(context: c)` method you call is [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-init).

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer to fix this apparent bug of SwiftUI / Xcode. Please be aware that this might be a problem if your view‘s code expects an entity obect without a context (i.e. `Entity(entity: Entity.entity(), insertInto: nil)`.
In that case call `Entity(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: context)!, insertInto: nil)` instead.

Comment: Well, this doesn't work as the Swift compiler requires that you call the designated initializer init(entity:, insertInto:)