# Combining Xcode Boilerplate Core Data/CloudKit Code with an MVVM architecture

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I’m practicing with creating a multiplatform App (could just as well be an iOS app) using the boilerplate code generated by Xcode when Core Data and CloudKit check boxes are selected upon project creation.

Xcode generates a `persistence.swift` file with the Core Data stack code and uses the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper in the `ContentView.swift` file. However, I’d like to move some of the more “view model” or non-UI boilerplate code out of `ContentView` and into a more MVVM-like view model class file so that I keep the `ContentView` focused on my UI.

I would like to continue using the provided `persistence.swift` file as my Core Data manager content.

Can I still use the power of `@FetchRequest` in the `ContentView` (I think it has to remain in my content view), while moving the other boilerplate code Xcode generated out of `ContentView` to a new view model class file? For example, I’m talking about the automatically generated code for `addItem()` and `deleteItem()`.

In other words, can I use both the `@FetchRequest` approach for accessing my entity model while also making my code fit a more MVVM architecture?

Comment: In my opinion, no you can’t. The view would hold the model objects rather than the view model. If you on the other hand have a view based on a list o navigation links then you could use a FerchRequest and ignore mvvm and instead use mvvm for the detail view and for adding objects

Comment: I think you can. I use a CoreData Manager that is completely generic for all the basic CRUD methods where `class CoreDataManager<T:NSManagedObject>` this serves as a superclass and my `EntityManagers` have unique methods for adding samples and returning the specific new object. [This is really helpful when you need Preview samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties/67408828#67408828). The ViewModels call on the manager to do any work just pass the object `manager.delete(object: anyObject)`