# Preview in Canvas stops working as soon as I use an object passed by another view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that uses `Core Data`, everything works fine when I compile to the simulator or a physical device, the issue is that for some reason the `Preview` in `Canvas` doesn't work. In the code below I'm passing an `Item` from `ItemsView` to `ItemView` through a `NavigationLink`, the issue starts as soon as I use the passed item anywhere in `ItemView`.  Again, the issue is only in `Canvas`. I know it's not a big deal since it compiles fine but I got used to seeing the preview when designing the interface.

### Error message:

> ItemsApp crashed due to an uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`. Reason: - [Item name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001d6c080.: The preview process appears to have crashed.

### Items View: Preview works fine.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ItemsView: View {
        @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel:CoreDataViewModel

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    List {
                        ForEach(coreDataViewModel.items) { item in
                            HStack{
                                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                                    Text(item.name ?? "")
                                    Text(item.price ?? "")
                                }
                                NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(coreDataViewModel: coreDataViewModel, selectedItem: item)){

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Item View: Preview doesn't work. The issue starts when I call `Text(selectedItem.name ?? "--")`

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ItemView: View {
        @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel
        @State var selectedItem: Item

        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text(selectedItem.name ?? "--") // this causes the issue
                }
            }
            .onAppear{
                Text(selectedItem.name ?? "--") // this causes the issue
            }
        }
    }

    struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ItemView(coreDataViewModel: CoreDataViewModel(), selectedItem: Item())
        }
    }
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Am I passing the item correctly?

Thanks

##### EDIT:

Corrected view name from `ServicesView` to `ItemView` in `NavigationLink` and `Previews`. Also added the error message.

##### EDIT:

Added CoreDataManager and CoreDataViewModel

### CoreDataManager

```
    class CoreDataManager{

        static let instance = CoreDataManager()
        
        let container: NSPersistentContainer
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext
        
        init(){
            container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataContainer")
            container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
                }
            }
            context = container.viewContext
        }
        
        func save(){
            do{
                try context.save()
            }catch let error{
                print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

### CoreDataViewModel

```
    class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject{
        
        let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
        
        @Published var items: [Item] = []
        
        init(){
            getItems()
        }
        
        func addItem(name: String, price: String){
            let item = Item(context: manager.context)
            item.name = name
            item.price = price
            save()
            getItems()
        }

        func getItems(){
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")

            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
            do{
                items =  try manager.context.fetch(request)
            }catch let error{
                print("Error fetching businesses. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        func save(){
            self.manager.save()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you mean, the Core Data stuff?

Comment: where and how do you use `ItemView`?

Comment: @fs_tigre, nope, pure SwiftUI - I have doubts CoreData matters here. If it is then it is not SwiftUI related issue.

Comment: in `ItemView` or  `ServicesView` whatever you want to call it, try using `var selectedItem: Item`
instead of `@State var selectedItem: Item`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PreviewProvider and ObservedObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties)

Comment: @workingdog - Changing `@State var selectedCar: Car` to `var selectedCar: Car` didn't make a difference, no preview. Thanks.

Comment: @Asperi -  I made some corrections to my original code since I had the wrong view name for `ItemView`, hopefully, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow:

1. In your `Persistance` struct declare a variable preview with your preview Items:

```
       static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.yourProperty = yourValue
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
           // error handling
        }
        return result
       }()
```

2. Create item from your viewContext and pass it to preview:

```
     struct YourView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
            let fetchedItem = (try! context.fetch(request).first)!
            YourView(item: fetchedItem)
        }
    }
```

Here is Persistence struct created by Xcode at the moment of the project initialization:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        let item = Item(context: viewContext)
        item.property = yourProperty
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
          
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCD")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
               
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Roma Kavinskyi -  Would you mind elaborating more on step 2? Where exactly do I need to add `static var preview` property? I just added the Core Data models for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: It's a struct created by Xcode automatically if you embed CoreData at the moment of project creation. I'll add to my answer

Comment: Oh, I actually created everything manually so, in my case it's the `CoreDataManager` file I recently added to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just edit init so it includes inMemory, as it's responsible for previews and add static preview var.

Comment: For some reason, I keep getting the following error.  `Cannot use instance member 'viewContext' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available` when I try to create an item in the Preview struct `var item = Item(context: viewContext)`

Comment: I got you. I modified the answer, so the property is fetched directly in the preview. Although, you don't need `@Environment(.\managedObjectContext)` anymore. Hope it'll work for you!

Comment: That did the trick, the preview is now working. Quick question, is the `var preview:` and the `inMemory` code strictly to create temporary objects to be used in the preview struct, is that correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Frankly saying I don't know how does it work under the hood, but I used to retrieve arrays of data and it has always been the one I set before. Seems like it's been deleted as soon as the preview stops.

Comment: It's ok, I'll look into it. Thanks a lot for your help.