# Creating example of Core Data entity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Creating an example for a struct is very easy and straightforward. For example,

```
import Foundation

struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let company: String

    static let example = User(id: UUID(), isActive: true, name: "Rick Owens", age: 35, company: "Rick Owens Inc.")
}
```

Now, how can I create an example if I made this an entity in core data? I can't just put `let example = CachedUser(id: UUID(), ...)` like I did with the struct. I want this example to be part of my core data automatically without having to manually create it by using forms, buttons, etc... Thanks in advance!

[image: Core Data Entity]

Comment: You can't do it the same way in CoreData. There are several ways to overcome this such as using the `preview` container for canvas, default values, having a method that pre propagates a sample object but it is hard to help without more info

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties/67408828#67408828) question

Comment: @loremipsum what other info would you need to help? I'm just asking generally, how would one could accomplish this. I would prefer just having a default CachedUser to use throughout my project.

Comment: Look at the question attached. The biggest thing is the purpose. If you only need it for previews then just create a user using the `preview` container  provided in Apple's sample project. If you want to preload the object with sample data all the time use the `awakeFromInsert` method provided by the entity

Comment: Create a hardcoded UUID and define that to be "example ID" (initialize it with all zeroes or whatever). Then when app starts check if this entry exists in database. If it exists, then return it. Otherwise create a new one, set default values and example ID, save it into database and return it.

Comment: You can do that with the link I attached. in the `addSample` method set your uuid. upon `init` of the service do your checks and create the sample as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if your default user exists in database. If it does not then you need to create one and save it. Something like the following would work if you have synchronous operations:

```
class CachedUser {
    
    static var example: CachedUser = {
        let exampleUUID = UUID(uuidString: "33041937-05b2-464a-98ad-3910cbe0d09e")!
        
        if let existingUser = Database.fetchUser(id: exampleUUID) {
            return existingUser
        } else {
            let newUser = CachedUser()
            // TODO: apply example values to user
            Database.saveUser(newUser)
            return newUser
        }
    }()
    
}
```

This will lazily return existing or generate a new user for you. This user will then be persistent in your database.

The code will only be executed once per session, first time you call `CachedUser.example`.

If you have your database setup asynchronous then with closures it should look something like this:

```
class User {
    
    static private(set) var example: User!
    
    static func prepareExampleUser(_ completion: () -> Void) {
        let exampleUUID = UUID(uuidString: "33041937-05b2-464a-98ad-3910cbe0d09e")!
        
        Database.fetchUser(id: exampleUUID) { user in
            if let user = user {
                example = user
                completion()
            } else {
                let newUser = User()
                newUser.id = exampleUUID
                // TODO: apply example values to user
                Database.saveUser(newUser) {
                    example = newUser
                    completion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But in this case it makes sense to warmup your application before you show screens that require this user to be present. You can for instance have a loading screen when your app first starts and continue to next screen once this method has finished...

```
// Loading screen enters
self.startLoading()
User.prepareExampleUser {
    self.navigateToNextScreen()
    self.stopLoading()
}
```

In both cases you now hold a static property to your example entry such as `User.example` which can be used anywhere.

But in both cases you may stumble to issue if user (if able to) deletes this entry from database. You would need to handle that case. Either prevent that action or create a new example user once the old one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To access this manager put

```
let mgr = CachedUserPersistenceManager()
```

In a ViewModel or a View

```
/// Manager for the Item entity
class CachedUserPersistenceManager: PersistenceManager<CachedUser>{
    let sampleUUID = UUID(uuidString: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")!

    init(isTest: Bool = false) {
        super.init(entityType: CachedUser.self, isTest: isTest)
        //Preloads the user
        preloadSample()
    }
    ///Preloads a sample object to the context
    func preloadSample(){
        let list = retrieveObjects(sortDescriptors: nil, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(CachedUser.uuid), sampleUUID as CVarArg)
        )
        if list.isEmpty{
            let sampleItem = createObject()
            sampleItem.uuid = sampleUUID
            save()
        }
    }
    override func addSample() -> CachedUser {
        let new = super.addSample() as CachedUser
        //add any sample code
        return new
    }
    
    override func createObject() -> CachedUser {
        super.createObject()!
    }
    override func updateObject(object: CachedUser) -> Bool {
        //Replace the uuid if needed
        if object.uuid == sampleUUID{
            object.uuid = UUID()
        }
        return super.updateObject(object: object)
    }
}
```

The generic classes that are a part of this code are below. You don't need them per say it just makes some of the code reusable through the app.

```
//Manager for any Entity
class PersistenceManager<T : NSManagedObject>{
    let serviceSD: CoreDataPersistenceService<T>
    internal init(entityType: T.Type, isTest: Bool = false) {
        self.serviceSD = CoreDataPersistenceService(isTest: isTest, entityType: entityType)
    }
    
    //MARK: convenience
    func addSample() -> T {
        let newItem = createObject()
        return newItem!
    }
    
    //MARK: Persistence Service Methods
    func createObject() -> T? {
        let result = serviceSD.createObject()
        return result
    }
    
    func updateObject(object: T) -> Bool {
        return serviceSD.updateObject(object: object)
    }
    
    func deleteObject(object: T) -> Bool {
        return serviceSD.deleteObject(object: object)
    }
    func deleteAllObjects(entityName: String, isConfirmed: Bool) -> Bool {
        return serviceSD.deleteAllObjects(isConfirmed: isConfirmed)
    }
    func retrieveObjects(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> [T]{
        return serviceSD.retrieveObjects(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate)
    }
    func retrieveObject(id: String) -> T? {
        return serviceSD.retrieveObject(sortDescriptors: nil, id: id).first
    }
    func resetChanges() {
        serviceSD.resetChanges()
    }
    func save() {
        _ = serviceSD.save()
    }
}
//Service for Any Entity
class CoreDataPersistenceService<T: NSManagedObject>: NSObject {
    var persistenceController: PersistenceController
    let entityType: T.Type
    
    required init(isTest: Bool = false, entityType: T.Type) {
        if isTest{
            self.persistenceController = PersistenceController.preview
        }else{
            self.persistenceController = PersistenceController.previewAware
        }
        self.entityType = entityType
        super.init()
    }
    //MARK: CRUD methods
    func createObject() -> T? {
        let result = entityType.init(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        return result
    }
    
    func updateObject(object: T) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        result = save()
        return result
    }
    func deleteObject(object: T) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        persistenceController.container.viewContext.delete(object)
        result = save()
        return result
    }
    
    func deleteAllObjects(isConfirmed: Bool) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        //Locked in so only the Generic "Item" can be deleted like this
        if entityType == Item.self && isConfirmed == true{
            let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: entityType.fetchRequest())
            do {
                try persistenceController.container.persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(deleteRequest, with: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                result = false
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func resetChanges()  {
        persistenceController.container.viewContext.rollback()
        _ = save()
        
    }
    
    func save() -> Bool {
        var result = false
        do {
            if persistenceController.container.viewContext.hasChanges{
                try persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
                result = true
                
            }else{
                result = false
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return result
    }
    func retrieveObject(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, id: String) -> [T]{
        return retrieveObjects(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id))
    }
    
    func retrieveObjects(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> [T]
    {
        
        let request = entityType.fetchRequest()
        if let sortDescriptor = sortDescriptors
        {
            request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor
        }
        if let predicate = predicate
        {
            request.predicate = predicate
        }
        do
        {
            let results = try persistenceController.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
            return results as! [T]
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
            return []
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The `previewAware` variable that is mentioned goes with the Apple standard code in the `PersistenceController`

It automatically give you the `preview` container so you don't have to worry about adapting your code for samples in Canvas. Just add the below code to the `PersistenceController`

```
static var previewAware : PersistenceController{
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1" {
        return PersistenceController.preview
    }else{
        return PersistenceController.shared
    }
}
```