# SwiftUI Preview doesn't work with Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have been trying to get my detail view working but when giving the preview arguments of the currently selected item from the list it keeps giving me an error `Cannot convert value of type 'Item.Type' to expected argument type 'Item'`

Here is the detailview

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FishDetailView: View {

    var item: Item

    @State var image : Data = .init(count: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title ?? "")
        Text(item.details ?? "")
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: item.imageData ?? self.image)!)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 34, height: 210)
            .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}

struct FishDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        FishDetailView(item: Item) **<--- THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE**
    }
}
```

Contentview.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTY

    @State var title: String = ""
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State var image : Data = .init(count: 0)
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

        @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    // MARK: - FUNCTION
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    //: MARK - BODY

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
              
                List {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: FishDetailView(item: item)) {
                            Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: item.imageData ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(systemName: "photo"))!)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 34, height: 210)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(item.details ?? "")")
                                
                            }//:HSTACK
                        }
                        // TODO: Insert timestamp here with .footnote font
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if showSheet {
                        AddFishView()
                    }
                }//: LIST
                .navigationBarTitle("Fishes", displayMode: .large)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                })
                   {
                    Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                    AddFishView()
                }
            } //: VSTACK
        } //: NAVIGATION
    }

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

The detailview does work if I remove the preview section of the code but it's not really ideal since I would like to see what I'm doing without having to open the app in simulator every time I do a change.

I can't seem to work out why it does it or how to fix it. Someone with better brains can help out?

The code is little bit messy because this is just a test I'm doing where I'm saving a users image into Core Data.

EDIT: already tried this that was suggested but didn't seem to fix my issue [PreviewProvider and ObservedObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties)

Here is the Item entity
[image: Entity image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PreviewProvider and ObservedObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408366/previewprovider-and-observedobject-properties)

Comment: In this case I would recommend protocol instead of direct dependency on Core Data Item and mock for Preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FishDetailView: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title ?? "")
        ...
        // fyi your image should be a transformable attribute on the Item entity
    }
}

struct PreviewTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var firstItem: Item? {
        let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = Item.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results?.first
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        if let firstItem {
            FishDetailView(item: firstItem)
        }
        else {
            Text("Item not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may work now, take note that uses a couple of force-unwraps which may cause your previews to explode and stop working later.

It is now also dependent on there being data in your Core Data database just for the preview to load.

Sure, they're only SwiftUI previews, but I'd still recommend using a plain Swift object (see [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mvvm+swift).

Comment: @acodeguy thank you i will be taking a look at that.

Comment: @acodeguy ok ok I removed the force-unwraps. We need a real NSManagedObject so validation works etc. in live preview.

Comment: It's definitely better without the force-unwraps, but the dependency on persistence would bother me if this were in a PR to go into a production app; if this is just a demo for learning, then that could always be taken into consideration on a future iteration/project

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to feed the preview a type rather than an instance of a type:

```swift
FishDetailView(item: Item)
```

Perhaps this is what you're trying to do instead:

```swift
let item = Item(/* init here */)
return FishDetailView(item: item)
```

or

```swift
FishDetailView(item: Item(/* init here */))
```

Comment: What is even supposed to place in the init here place?

Comment: @John I couldn't see the `Item` class or struct so I just left how to initialize it a blank. If you post it's code I'd be happy to help further with creating one

Comment: Init is it supposed to be like title: "the title"

Comment: Depends on the structure of `Item`, without it I'm blind here, but let's say you have a class named `Person`:

```swift
class Person {
var name: String
}
```

In order to create an instance of a person, you'd need to do something like this:

```swift
let John = Person(name: "John")
```

Comment: I added the Item entity picture. Hopefully it helps. I have selected the codegen to Class selection instead of manual/none. Do I need to make my own struct of the Item. Sorry this core data is new to me since I just started learning it.

Comment: Previews can get a little difficult to manage when you involve Core Data entities; I always go down the route of using plain Swift object to represent them, so instead of an `Item`, I'd have an `ItemViewModel` or something that holds similar data needed to represent the Core Data model.

Comment: So best way would be to just, for example hard code the images and titles and do the design and after that place the "real data" in there?

Comment: Thank you @acodeguy you have been really helpful :)

Comment: Create a new sample SwifUI project and select CoreData checkbox, see how apple generates data used in preview. You can just have it in memory without persisting for preview

Comment: @user1046037 The problem is I have a details view where I have all the data that was given when creating a new item. And in detail view I get error **Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call**. And when I give the parameters** item: Item** it gives and error **Cannot convert value of type 'Item.Type' to expected argument type 'Item'**.

Comment: @acodeguy has given the correct answer, IMHO if you are not clear with the answer it would be better to learn the difference between an instance of a class and the class.